# Mapping JSON to Java Class using Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, mapping

I have a scenario where at run time depending upon the JSON values I have to convert them to choose which JAVA classes we have to use to initialize them.
Below are the two JSON examples

**JSON Example1:**

```
{
  "parentVal1" : "parent Val 1",
  "parentVal2" : "parent val 2",
  "childVal1" : "child Val 1",
  "childVal2" : {
    "childPropVal1" : "child prop 1",
    "grandChild" : {
      "maleGrandChildVal1" : "male grand child 1",
      "maleGrandChildVal2" : "male grand child 2"
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON Example2:**

```
{
  "parentVal1" : "parent Val 1",
  "parentVal2" : "parent val 2",
  "childVal1" : "child Val 1",
  "childVal2" : {
    "childPropVal1" : "child prop 1",
    "grandChild" : {
      "femaleGrandChildVal1" : "female grand child 1",
      "femaleGrandChildVal2" : "female grand child 2"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, corresponding JAVA classes which I made and class diagram are

```
public class Parent{
  private String parentVal1;
  private String parentVal2;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Child extends{
  private String childVal1;
  private ChildProperty childVal2;

  //getters and setters
}

public class ChildProperty{
  private String childPropVal1;
  private GrandChildAbstract grandChild;

  //getters and setters 
}

public class GrandChildAbstract{

}

public class MaleGrandChild extends GrandChildAbstract{
  private String maleGrandChildVal1;
  private String maleGrandChildVal2;
  //setters and getters
}

public class FemaleGrandChild extends GrandChildAbstract{
  private String femaleGrandChildVal1;
  private String femaleGrandChildVal2;

  //setters and getters
}
```

[image]

The problem is on the runtime I will get a JSON and have to decide whether it belongs to `MaleGrandChild or FemaleGrandChild` depending upon the `ChildProperty.childPropVal1` that I get from JSON.

Can anyone help me are there any way which could initialize the `ChildProperty.grandChild` property with the respective `FemaleGrandChild or MaleGrandChild` object.

*I am using Jackson for conversion from JSON to JAVA.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read about polymorphic deserialization with Jackson? http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization.

Usually you provide the type using `JsonTypeInfo`. That allows Jackson to understand how to map a specific object.

If you can't really do any manipulation on the JSON (if not sourced by you, for example), you can write a custom mapper (not straightforward) or you can those properties to a simple `Map`, and let another part of your application deal with the type.